# Reducing power consumption and background processes on Cyanogenmod 12?

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one

Since I upgraded OnePlus One to Cyanogenmod 12 from 11s, it only brought troubles.

I had to increase maximum current to be able to boot the phone and there are constant background processes that I can't seem to be able to turn off.

Does anyone know what could be running on Cyanogenmod 12 even if I turned off pretty much every new feature? I want to check if I can fix this before reverting back to Cyanogenmod 11s.

Two screenshots below were taken few seconds apart. Whatever is casing current to rise in screenshot 2 repeats every minute or two for several seconds. Phone is left at idle mode with `Screen_Bright_Wake_Lock` enabled.

[image: Clean Idle current]

[image]

[image: Some background process is running]

[image]

Comment: How did you upgrade? Is the device rooted and custom recovery installed?

Comment: I did an upgrade from scratch so had to calibrate the battery, because I wasn't getting even 2hrs Screen on Time. Many services are hibernated mostly using Greenify and I'm using AK kernel since Stock didn't do well in my case. To be honest, you should try searching on [OnePlus Forums](https://forums.oneplus.net/). They've lots of guides to deal with this.

Comment: I upgraded normally once upgrade became available. I did root it and install custom recovery later. Thanks, yes. I probably will check there too.

Comment: I keep seeing this in logCat: 
`I/wpa_supplicant( 1545): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED`